# Parsing files with Python

Tags: python, parsing, object

What type of Python objects should I use to parse files with a specific syntax? Also what sort of loop should be followed to make it through the file. Should one pass be sufficient? Two, three?

Comment: Answer: "The appropriate ones. A for loop should suffice. Perhaps. Could be." Hopefully, my answer is as detailed, informative and precise as your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the grammar. You can use [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) instead of implementing your own parser. It is very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You should offer more information about your aims ...

- What kind of file
- What structure? Tab separated? XML - like?
- What kind of encoding?
- Whats the target structure?
- Do you need to reparse the file in a regular time period (like an interpreter)?

Answer (score 1):

how complex the syntax is? are you inventing a new one or not?

for a complex language, consider bison bindings like lex + pybison.

if you can decide what syntax to use, try YAML.

Comment: I'd suggest JSON to YAML, if only because it's in the standard library and YAML isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It does not depend on your programming language (python) if your parser will have one, two, three or n passes. It depends on the grammar of the syntax you are trying to parse.

If the syntax is complex enough I would recommend LEX/YACC combo as Francis said.